# In C#.net, How I get the Content of File Sent to Print to normal office printer

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

A file is sent to print,and **I want to store the content of that file in a notepad file**. Means I want to maintain A print Record, that **which file & content of that file** is printed by the printer in seprate notepad or any word document.

**File contains only text data**. Not images

how I do this. Any suggestions for doing this in C#.Net. please share some code so that I can understand.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking how to intercept and log print jobs?

Comment: did you tried XPS.? It may be useful for you.

Comment: No I dont tried XPS. please tell how do I use this  kovilpatti C sharper

Comment: I want to keep **record** or we can say **watch** on the print jobs without knowing the User. File is printing, I want to store the content or data from that printed file  into another text file.

Comment: I don't want to Intercept print jobs, but want to keep watch if there any print goes from system then one notepad file automatically created by the system. but user should not get this. Cory Nelson

Comment: Try monitoring creation of `Win32_PrintJob` - (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/D884ACBA-E1B2-4D24-9B55-15D175A163D9(v=vs.85,d=lightweight).aspx) instances with WMI. For each `PrintJob` you can read the `Document` property to find out which file was printed. I think you'll have to handle each file type individually - Notepad files as is, Office documents using the OpenXML SDK or Office Automation, etc.

Comment: Some other options [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/423178/printing-order-intercept-with-csharp)

Comment: More details [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/aded6395-a1e7-4fbc-b9f6-ff4c7c346016/).

Comment: Thank you.. for sharing @ Zev Spitz. I think your information will help me.

Comment: PSK ! i am also stuck in a similar problem i have searched the internet alot. but that didnt do me any good. please let me know if you have found a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can monitor the print jobs using FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification , which will help you get information about the job fired to the printer like job name, status, pages printed, etc. You can refer to [Monitor Printer Queue](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/51085/Monitor-jobs-in-a-printer-queue-NET)

and [Print Spooler Monitor](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martijnh/archive/2009/08/05/printmonitor-a-c-print-spooler-monitor.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0)

However you cannot save the content of the job in a file (easily), as the print job has already been processed by the printer driver and is spooler ready and will be in raw PCL/PJL/other format.

The only way you can "capture" content is by writing your own print monitor