# How to get currently printed documents programmatically?

Tags: windows, winapi, printing

I found [FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162722%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. Is it possible to get documents that are currently printed by using it?

I want to get something like HDC - to save it to .pdf, .png or similar format.

I can't find any information about that in documentation. If no, maybe there are other ways to achieve this?

Comment: You may want to try the `EnumJobs` function, which can retrieve a  JOB_INFO_N (1 to 3) with fields named `pDocument`

Comment: But I don't want name (MSDN cite: A pointer to a null-terminated string that specifies the name of the print job (for example, "MS-WORD: Review.doc")), I want to get something like HDC - to save it to .pdf, .png or similar format. `pDocument` won't be good, because user can also print "Untitled" document - so no path to printed document exists.

Comment: I think you ask too much to the Spool API, but I may be wrong. Good luck.

Comment: [_"you cannot save the content of the job in a file (easily), as the print job has already been processed by the printer driver and is spooler ready and will be in raw PCL/PJL/other format."_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946174/in-c-net-how-i-get-the-content-of-file-sent-to-print-to-normal-office-printer).

Comment: Thanks, but maybe capture can happen before printer driver had processed it? I read about print monitor, and I think it's that what I was asking for (although it's a lot of work). If you want, you can post your comment as answer and I'll accept it. However, I'm still looking for shorter solution...

Comment: @mkzwm
hi i am also stuck in a similar problem if you have found a solution please post it here

Comment: @Aitizazk did you find?